# How to make file requests work when using multiple reverse proxies by path in apache server?

Tags: apache, proxy, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to use Apache to host a server that will reverse proxy to multiple other servers. The way I'm attempting to do it is through the following:

```
<Location /server1/>
    ProxyPass http://192.168.0.31/
    ProxyPassReverse  http://192.168.0.31/
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Location>

<Location /server2/>
    ProxyPass http://192.168.0.32/
    ProxyPassReverse  http://192.168.0.32/
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Location>
```

The proxy server is at 192.168.0.30. The problem I'm encountering is that requests/file accesses aren't being served by the right server. The client requests it from the proxy server rather than from server1 or server2, and the proxy server doesn't have the files.

```
GET http://192.168.0.30/php/file.php 404 (Not Found)
```

Any tips on what to change to resolve this issue are appreciated. Note that this isn't supposed to be a form of load balancing - server 1 and server 2 should be accessible separately.

Comment: Does server1 and server2 have the file you are looking for and have the proper permissions? Can you post your error logs from the proxy server and one of the other servers?

Comment: server1 and server2 both have the file needed. In this case the problem is that the client is requesting it from the original proxy server, and the request isn't being forwarded to the appropriate place. From checking error.log in all servers, there is nothing new after the init lines.

Is there a way to use rewrite rules for this?

Comment: I apologize for not noticing this the first time. You never actually call any of your other servers.You posted "GET http://192.168.0.30/php/file.php 404 (Not Found)" and yet your .30 (original server) doesn't know about the file.php because it doesn't exist on .30. If you want to access that file from one of the other servers you need to also add in http://originalserver/server1/php/file.php etc. You also aren't using Apache as a proxy load balancer. You just set up a location to essentially point at some other server.